# How conditional Goto will work on Soap UI

Tags: soapui

This is my requirement.

I will run the Retrieve Question Request. It will pull out question id and question.

Based on the question id, i need to pass the answer on the 2nd request.

How to achieve this?

It is a kind of switch. But i dont know how to use in this Soap UI. Please let me know.

Regards,
Chandra

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved this by groovy script.. still if someone finds the answer through conditionalgoto please let me know..

```
def qid = context.expand( '${Retrieve the Question#ResponseAsXml#declare namespace ns1=\'host/mrs/1/security/credential/challenge'; //ns1:Response[1]/ns1:challenge[1]/ns1:e[1]/ns1:questionID[1]}' )
log.info(qid)
if (qid=='1')
{
testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.setPropertyValue("answer","Nothing")
//log.info(answer)
}
else
{
testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.setPropertyValue("answer","Motorola")
//log.info(answer)
}
//log.info(testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.getPropertyValue
```